# Object Oriented Programming Parent and Child Class

Tags: java, php, oop

Hi guys I just want to ask if you create a class do you still need to create Parent as a basis to the new class or child class like if i want to create a Student Class should i still create a Person Class so the Student Class inherits all the properties of the Person is it really necessary ? or i am the one who only think this kind of doings thanks a lot for your help in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to have any other classes representing a person, for example, a Teacher class, then you don't have to. But chances are, thus I will say you better to create a Person class with basic info about the person, i.e first name, surname, date of  birth, and whatever information you need about a person. Then your Student class will inherit all the properties from the parent class thus, the Student class will have fields like studentId and another student specific information. The name and dob will be inherited from the Person class.

Answer (score 2):

No if you want to create a `Student` class, you do not have to create a `Person` class. Please remember one thing that your Student class implicitly inherits from a base class of java library, that base class is `java.lang.Object`. All classes of Java are either direct or indirect children of `java.lang.Object`.